# Why my android application takes to photo with one clik?

Tags: android, delphi, photo

I wrote a Delphi 10.3 CE multidevice app that uses a button to take photos. The code i used is this (simplyfied) :

```
unit uFormes;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.TabControl,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Gestures, FMX.TreeView, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base, FMX.ListView,
  System.Rtti, FMX.Grid.Style, FMX.Grid, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Edit,
  FMX.Memo, Data.DB, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, FMX.EditBox, FMX.NumberBox, FMX.text, System.Sensors, System.Sensors.Components,
  FMX.ExtCtrls, System.ImageList, FMX.ImgList, FMX.Objects, System.Actions,
  FMX.ActnList, FMX.StdActns, FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions, System.Permissions;

type
TTabbedForm = class(TForm)
TabControl1: TTabControl;
TabItem1: TTabItem;
TabItem2: TTabItem;
GestureManager1: TGestureManager;
CornerButton1: TCornerButton;
ActionList1: TActionList;
TakePhotoFromCameraAction1: TTakePhotoFromCameraAction;
Image1: TImage;
procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
procedure TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
procedure SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
procedure PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
procedure DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
  TabbedForm: TTabbedForm;

implementation

uses
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
    Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
    Androidapi.JNI.Net,
    Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
    FMX.Helpers.Android,
    Androidapi.JNIBridge,
    Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os
{$ENDIF}
    FMX.Consts,
    FMX.Platform,
    FMX.VirtualKeyboard,
    EncdDecd,
    System.IOUtils,
    inifiles,
    FMX.DialogService;

{$R *.fmx}



procedure TTabbedForm.PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
begin
  // 3 permission involved
  if (Length(AGrantResults) = 3)
  and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted)
  and (AGrantResults[1] = TPermissionStatus.Granted)
  and (AGrantResults[2] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
  else
    ShowMessage('δεν έχει δοθεί άδεια') ;
end;

procedure TTabbedForm.DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
begin
  TDialogService.ShowMessage('πρέπει να χρησιμοποιηθεί η κάμερα',
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      APostRationaleProc;
    end);
end;

procedure TTabbedForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
    permCam, permRead, permWrite: string;

begin
    // Request permissions
  permCam := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.CAMERA);
  permRead := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  permWrite := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([permCam, permRead, permWrite], PermissionRequestResult, DisplayRationale);
end;

procedure TTabbedForm.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
begin
    Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
end;

end.
```

Each time i clik the button, i noticed that my cellphone takes two photos (one about 300KB and one about 7 MB). This isn't a cellphone's issue because i tested manual and takes one shot.

Comment: Please [edit] to show your actual code and full details in the body of your question. Don't rely on older questions on SO and say you're using the same code, and certainly not comments. Those can be easily deleted.

Comment: Where is the actual button click code? You have an event handler declared, but where is the implementation?

Comment: There isn't a click event, only an assigned action to the button (procedure TTabbedForm.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all the "fluff" from your code, I came up with this:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    Button1: TButton;
    TakePhotoFromCameraAction1: TTakePhotoFromCameraAction;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TPermissionsService.DefaultService.RequestPermissions(['android.permission.CAMERA', 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE',
    'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'], PermissionRequestResult);
end;

procedure TForm1.PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
begin
  // Not checking the result because I know I will accept
end;

procedure TForm1.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
end;
```

Using that (and Secure File Sharing enabled in the Entitlements), it ends up with precisely *one* image in my photos when I click the button that has the action attached to it. This is using Delphi 10.3.1, and a Nexus 5X with Android 9. I don't recall any changes from 10.3 that would explain the difference.

Comment: In my cellphone (CUBOT P20, android 8.0.0), removing what you removed, still saves 2 copies. one with size 190.83 KB and one 6.45 MB. But the most strange to me is that the app saves the taken bitmap to a stream with size 404 KB !! i used this code for see it
procedure TTabbedForm.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
var mStream : TmemoryStream;
begin
    Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
    mStream := TmemoryStream.create;
    Image1.Bitmap.SaveToStream(mStream);
    showmessage(inttostr(mStream.size));
    mStream.Free;
end;

Comment: I noticed that the Timage component has the property MultiResBitmat : (TFixedMultiResBitmap). Has this any impact to taking 2+1 different pictures ?

Comment: No, the TImage is completely separate from the picture taking process